# A vector component comparison

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, physics

I came across the following "mathematical difficulty" while I was studying physics and non-inertial reference frames.
Therefore, I'm interested in the case $n=3$, but I think I can formulate the problem in a slight more general context.

Suppose you have a particle (or point) with position vector $\textbf{x}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t) \textbf{e}_i$ with respect to a reference frame (here $\textbf{e}_i$ is supposed to be the $i$th coordinate vector of an orthonormal basis) which can move only in one direction and that cannot change is versus (this means that the particle moves along a straight line with unit vector $\textbf{x}/\lvert \textbf{x}\rvert$).
At time $t$, its velocity vector is $\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x}(t)$.
It seems there are two basic possibilities to express this quantity:

(1)
The first one is (the vectors of the orthonormal basis being independent of $t$)
$$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{dt}x_i(t) \textbf{e}_i;$$

(2)
the second one amounts to decompose (e.g. polar coordinates) the position vector $\textbf{x}(t)=\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert \hat{\textbf{x}}$ and apply the usual rules for differentiation (for simplicity, I denote by $\hat{\textbf{x}}=\frac{\textbf{x}(t)}{\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert}$ the normalized vector, which does not depend on $t$):
$$\frac{d}{dt}\textbf{x}(t)
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)\frac{d}{dt}x_i(t)}{\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert}\hat{\textbf{x}}
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)\frac{d}{dt}x_i(t)}{\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)\textbf{e}_i}{\lvert{\textbf{x}(t)\rvert}}
=\sum_{i=1}^n\Biggl[\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k(t)\frac{d}{dt}x_k(t)}{\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert^2} x_i(t)\Biggr]\textbf{e}_i.$$

Clearly, the components of the two expressions must be equal, but it doesn't seems so evident to me.
Can you help me to understand what is going on? (I hope there are no mistakes in my computations).
Finally, please, tell me if I need to elaborate further my question.

(If the tags do not match the question properly, feel free to correct them.)

Comment: Your first formula doesn't have the information "only moves in one direction" baked in. To move between the two you'll need to leverage that $\hat{\bf x}$ is constant probably. This gives you $n$ formulas $d/dt(x_i(t)/|x(t)|) = 0$

Comment: @Glare And this should be the clue I was looking for, though apperently trivial. Indeed, a simple derivarition of your $n$ additional formulas gives $d/dt(x_i(t))=[\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(t)]/\lvert\textbf{x}(t)\rvert^2$, which in turn should link the above two expressions (1), (2). Please, give a check to avoid any other mistake. And, above all, thank you.

Comment: @Glare Unfortunately, I was wrong: a more careful checking seems to show the conclusion is not immediate, and I was not able to link (1), (2). This evening I'll write down my doubts.

Comment: I think you meant $d/dt(x_i(t)) = x_i(t)[{\bf x}(t)\cdot{\bf x}'(t)]/|{\bf x}(t)|^2$, since this is what you actually want for (2) to become (1). It's also what I found when I checked it myself.

Edit: didn't see your second comment. Anyway, $d/dt(x_i(t)/|{\bf x}(t)|)=0$ definitely becomes the formula I just wrote, so I encourage you to try working out the derivative again.

Comment: @Glare Yes, you are definitely right. Thank you very much for your kind help. If you want, post an answer and I'll upvote It.